# How can you programmatically bring up keyboard with CCTextField?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-iphone-3

I have a `CCTextField` that is hidden until the user taps on an object, which then adds it to the node tree and it's visible.

Currently, the user must then tap the `CCTextField` to activate the iOS keyboard and begin entering text.

Is there a way to programmatically initiate the keyboard appearing ?

`becomeFirstResponder` isn't working.

Comment: does assigning the textfield `firstResponder` status not work? I haven't used the library, but the documentation on the `CCTextField` class says it encapsulates `UITextField` so I presume it should work the same, no?

Comment: I presumed it would as well. I did try `becomesFirstResponder` on the text field property initially, but no dice. I think it "should" work, but did find a workaround. But am wondering if possibly I worked around an intentional roadblock :)  we shall see...

Comment: ahaha, good to know! Thanks for posting an update to this as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dug a little deeper into the `CCTextField` class code, and cocos2D adds the `UITextField` property as a subview of the cocos2d view.

For some reason though, this didn't work :

`[myCCTextField.textField becomeFirstResponder];`

This is what I did, and it worked :

`[[CCDirector sharedDirector] view]subviews[0] becomeFirstResponder];`

If you have multiple `CCTextField`s you are obviously going to have to determine the index of your desired text field that you'd like to edit.